# SQL select statement column order with union

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way in union tables to ignore first select column order and to match records by column names?

Take for example this:

```
// TEST1 table:
|  a  |  b  |
-------------
|  3  |  5  |

// TEST2 table:
|  b  |  a  |
-------------
|  4  |  9  |

select a, b from TEST1 union ( select b, a from TEST2)

// The result must be a table like the on below:
|  a  |  b  |
-------------
|  3  |  5  |
-------------
|  9  |  4  |

// BUT, actually is:
|  a  |  b  |
-------------
|  3  |  5  |
-------------
|  4  |  9  |
```

UPDATE:

The name of the columns and their numbers are the same, just the order is different and I CAN'T change the second select column order.

I'm asking for a way to ignore the default sql union behavior and to tell it to match the column name, not the order of passing

Comment: my column names and number are the same, just can't guarantee their order.

Comment: I can't change the second select column order...If I had that option I woudn't ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UNION** doesn't have this kind of fonctionnality.

You have to find a workaround for instance :

```
select concat('a',a) as a, concat('b',b) as b from TEST1 union ( select concat('b',b) as b, concat('a',a) as a from TEST2)
```

You will have something like that :

```
|  a  |  b  |
-------------
|  a3  |  b5  |
-------------
|  b4  |  a9  |
```

Then you can parse it and reorder it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the fields in the table is irrelevant. It's the order that you specify the fields in your union's sub-queries that counts.

Currently you have:

```
    select a, b from TEST1
union      |  |
    select b, a from TEST2)
```

when it should be

```
    select a, b from TEST1
union      |  |
    select a, b from TEST2
```

The ONLY time that field-ordering in the table definition would matter is if you were doing `select *`.